# Missing Linq to SQL namespace in Visual Studio 2012 Web Site Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql

The hosting provider for one of the web sites I manage has forced us to only be able to modify the site as a web project instead of as a web application. When it was initially a web application it was working fine, but after converting to a web site project I had many issues involving missing namespaces and references and was able to resolve them by placing all of my libraries inside of the top-level App_Code folder of the web site. I have one last issue with my linq-to-sql class - in Visual Studio the class is recognized now that it's in the top level App_Code folder, but when I call a page which references it I get the following error:

`The type or namespace name 'LIFH_IntakesDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Initially there was no namespace whatsoever, but in my attempts to fix this I addded a "LIHS" namespace and placed the Data Context within that:

[image]

Here are the references for the site:

[image]

And here is the Build configuration:
[image]

And, here is my directory structure (Linq-to-SQL class is referenced in the circled "reports.aspx" page):[image]

Code in reports.aspx:
[image]

Both the master page and the reports page are both in the LIHS namespace.

I am developing on Visual Studio 2012 and the application pool is set to .NET 2.0. The hosting provider does not allow anything above 2.0.

I have researched and found many references to my issue but most of them solve the problem by converting to a web application, which I cannot do, or by changing the target framework or by using a namespace, which I have done, but to no avail. I would appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: Um, `LIFairHousingIntakesDataContext` (from the error message) and `LIFH_IntakesDataContext` (from your code and the designer) aren't the same thing... where are you using `LIFairHousingIntakesDataContext`?

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks for pointing out the typographical error! It has been corrected in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Pay Attention: Linq is only available in .Net 3.5 and later
If you are using .net 2.0 it wont work.

You can see it in your screenshot.

Hope it helps.
Mike